# General Dynamic Selectbox Question

Tags: jquery

This is just a general question...I'm in the process of trying to figure out how to fire an event (call a function) to populate a select (dropdown) with options once the user clicks on it. The core question is:
How can I fire an event only when the select (or similar) is clicked...without firing the event again on change (on select...when the user chooses something)?

Comment: how about firing the event on `.focus()`

Comment: i have updated the demo check it and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

> - **DEMO:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/general-dynamic-selectbox-question

```
$(function() {
    var options = ["the", "brown", "fox", "jump"];
    $('#create-select').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var select = '<select id="select-create">\n';
        $.each(options,function(i, item) {
            select += '<option ' + (i === 0 ? 'selected': '') + ' value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>\n';
        });
        select +=  '</select>'; 
        $(this).fadeOut(200,function (){
         $(select).insertAfter(this);    
           $(this).remove();     
        });
    });
    $('#select-create').live('change',function() {
        alert($(this).val())
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for spending your time on this, it works well.  I ended up using a multi-select ui plugin that we're using in other places on the site: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#single. There is a method called beforeopen: that allows us to execute the function we need prior opening the select(s)...

Comment: @sysmnt: no problem bro, anyway if my answer ask your question pls, at least check it, so it will be considered closed. ;)